# Show List From controller to Razor View C# MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

i want show data from controller to view Razor.

i have controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    GetListPermission requestingMenuPermission = new GetListPermission(new Guid(userId));
    ViewBag.Menus = requestingMenuPermission.MenuHeader1;
    return View();
}
```

result of the code :

```
ViewBag.Menus = requestingMenuPermission.MenuHeader1;
```

as attach picture :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pahe2.png)

how i show that data in razor view.?

thank you very much.

Comment: `@foreach (var menu in ViewBag.Menus) { @menu.Something }`. Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. This site is not a replacement for tutorials or books.

Comment: Hello @CodeCaster, thank you for your answer.

i want show data MenuDetail in list MenuHeader. how i show it.? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem has been resolved.

```
@foreach (var menu in ViewBag.Menus)
  {
     @menu.MenuTittle
       @foreach (var menudetail in menu.MenuDetail)
       {
         @menudetail.MenuTittle.ToString();
         @menudetail.ReadAction.ToString();
         @menudetail.MenuController.ToString();
       }
}
```

thank you..